# Does browser need to be refreshed to see new cookie? Confusing issue I've noticed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, cookies

I am working through the Udacity course on web app development using Python and Google App Engine.  During a lesson on setting cookies (to count visitor count) and hashing I noticed something that is confusing me:

For fun I decided to print out the cookie value of 'visits' before and after adding 1 more visit. Here is the output:

```
5|e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5  [[[this is cookie before adding 1 to it]]
You've been here 6 times!  [[this is printed after adding 1 to cookie, but is not the cookie]]
5|e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5  [[this is printing the cookie after one has been set using "Set-Cookie"]]
```

The 6 in the middle line is correct. Using a cookie viewer I have verified that it matches the cookie. So the "5" in the first line is also correct (because this line is reading the cookie before 1 was added).

What is confusing me is that I also print out the cookie value AFTER adding 1, and it's STILL prints "5" -- even though the cookie has already been reset to 6.

Why is that?  Does the browser need to be refreshed before the new cookie is read correctly or something?

Here is the code in question:
    class CookiePage(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        visits = 0
        visits_cookie_str = self.request.cookies.get('visits')
        self.write(visits_cookie_str) # this is the first line printed
        self.write("\n")

```
    if visits_cookie_str:
        cookie_val = check_secure_val(visits_cookie_str)
        visits = int(cookie_val)

    visits += 1

    new_cookie_val = make_secure_val(str(visits))

    self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'visits=%s' % new_cookie_val)
    self.write("You've been here %s times!\n" % visits) # this is the 2nd line printed
    cookie = self.request.cookies.get('visits')
    self.write(cookie) # this is the 3rd line printed which SHOULD match the one above it but doesn't
```

Comment: How are you setting the cookie? Via Javascript or on the server? Also, can you show us some actual code?

Comment: It's being set using Python and Google App Engine.  I will update my question with the code.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie is stored in a header sent by the browser when it makes a request, if you set a cookie on the server, the value of that cookie will generally not be available until the *next* request after the browser has seen it and can send the new header value.

**UPDATE**

After seeing your code, the situation I described is indeed what is happening. You're setting a header in the response which is sent back to the client to set a cookie. However, the client will not see this cookie until the request is finished being processed. `self.request` will NOT be updated because it reflects the current request being processed, before the cookie was set.

If you want to keep track of the value during the request, you'll have to store it in a variable somewhere.